# WSL: The GUI linux app opens funny in WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I open IntelliJ from WSL Ubuntu it does not render correctly and is displaced like the image below. How to fix it? (Sometimes it opens normally).

[image]

Comment: Which WSL and Windows versions is this question about?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem as well. This [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg/issues/1130) described the same issue. I was able to solve it with `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt upgrade` and restarting the wsl container with `wsl --shutdown`, `wsl`. If that doesn't work others mention updating NVidia drivers or downgrading wsl versions to 2.0.4.